# What are the arguments to put in eclipse subversion merge program arguments to make subversive work with TortoiseMerge?

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subversive, tortoisemerge

What are the arguments to put in eclipse subversion merge program arguments to make subversive work with TortoiseMerge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [TortoiseMerge Command Line Switches](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseMerge_en/tme-automation.html).

If you were using [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) (which I personally prefer), it tells you right in the dialog. :)

[image: Subclipse diff/merge dialog]

I prefer it since it is simpler to setup, and has always worked solidly for me.

Comment: I've used both, and at least in the past had issues with subversive - in particular, with installing it. It's annoying that the SVN connectors must be installed separately from subversive itself - while I realize the reasons are licensing, I'm the user and I'm going to go with what is easier to use and works best for me. I just tested setting it up again, and encountered error dialogs and had to manually get the svn connectors from an update site since the new "connector discovery" feature didn't work. That said, I should probably downgrade my "strongly prefer" to "I personally prefer"